# How to install GCC/G++ 8 on CentOS

Tags: gcc, centos, g++, software-collections, redhat-dts

I'm used to install packages on Debian/Ubuntu distributions, but now I need to install `gcc` and `g++` version 8.*. There is only version 4.* in CentOS repositories. What's the correct way to install them manually?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

CentOS 8 already comes with GCC 8.

On CentOS 7, you can install GCC 8 from Developer Toolset.  First you need to enable the Software Collections repository:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

Then you can install GCC 8 and its C++ compiler:

```
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
```

To switch to a shell which defaults `gcc` and `g++` to this GCC version, use:

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash
```

You need to wrap all commands under the `scl` call, so that the process environment changes performed by this command affect all subshells.  For example, you could use the `scl` command to invoke a shell script that performs the required actions.

Comment: You can find more details for working with software collections in [How to install GCC 8 and LLVM 6 on RHEL](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/05/yum-install-gcc-8-clang-6/) including how to permanently enable the collection so that gcc/g++ 8 will always be in your path.

Comment: # yum install centos-release-scl
No match for argument: centos-release-scl

I'm using CentOS 8. Where can I get the packages installed here?

Comment: It helps on CentOS 7. Just replace the `8` with `10` to install G++/CCC 10.

Comment: Answer didn't work for CentOS7. Attempted `scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash` and the bash shell still uses the old gcc/g++. HOWEVER `scl enable devtoolset-8 -- gcc --version` does work.

Answer (score 20):

[Permanently adding DTS to your development environment](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/hello-world/#fndtn-windows)

After installing the devtoolset:

```
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
```

You can also use the following command, to make DTS the default:

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-8
```

The benefit of this command is that it can be added to **.bashrc**, so that you don't have to run the scl command every time you login:

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash
```

Answer (score 5):

CentOS 8, to install dev tools: `sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"`

https://linuxhint.com/install_gcc_build_tools_centos8/

Comment: The most convenient method!