# Enable devtoolset-8 for zsh on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, zsh, gnome-terminal, devtoolset

I run Centos 7, and I installed `devtoolset-8` in order to get gcc 8.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345845/7613809) I found how to enable it for `bash`, which is done simply by adding

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-8
```

to `.bashrc`.

If I append this to the `.zshrc`, or run that command from within `zsh`, I get

```
/usr/bin/scl_source:58: = not found
```

It seems that in `scl-utils` there is no `zsh` support (see [this discussion](https://github.com/sclorg/scl-utils/pull/16)).

**Is there a way of enabling `devtoolset-8` it for `zsh`?**

Currently, I set the gnome terminal emulator to run `zsh` instead of the shell (`bash`), so I thought that the correct version of `devtools` would be inherited by `zsh`, but it's not the case.
As I open the terminal, `% gcc --version` (in `zsh`) gives

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

but if I first run `bash`, then `$ gcc --version` gives what's expected,

```
gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

Apparently, I don't understand what `gnome-terminal` is actually doing when I have it run `zsh` instead of the `bash` shell.
**What am I not understanding?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work-around that I found is to set `gnome-terminal` to run

```
bash -c "$HOME/.bashrc; exec zsh"
```

as a custom command in place of the default shell, which is equivalent to opening a terminal emulator with

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "$HOME/.bashrc; exec zsh"
```

adapted from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/974782).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could also use:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
```

Tested on RHEL7.6 for package rh-php73, it worked:

```
source /opt/rh/rh-php73/enable
```

Found the hint [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175851/how-to-permanently-enable-scl-centos-6-4)