# Can not find required gcc version after devtoolset installation

Tags: linux, gcc, devtoolset

I am using Centos 7 with kernel 3.10.0

My current gcc version is 4.8.5 and I am trying to install gcc 7 or later versions. I have followed instructions from [How to install GCC/G++ 8 on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345373/how-to-install-gcc-g-8-on-centos)

When I try `scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash`, it shows

> Unable to open /etc/scl/conf/devtoolset-8!

Then I have checked in /etc/scl/conf/ where there is one file named 'devtoolset-9'. But I was expecting devtoolset-8.

If I run `yum list installed | grep devtoolset`, it shows packages related to devtoolset-8 and devtoolset-7. But I can not switch to gcc 7 or 8 because of that previous error. If I run  `scl enable devtoolset-9 -- bash`, it does not change to the gcc version, stays at the default gcc. What may go wrong and how do I switch to gcc 7 or 8 in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue that you are facing and this is how I got it fixed:

1. Just want to be careful, you need to exist the Terminal and open a fresh one to start.  This way, you are not under any devtoolset's bash.
2. Go to /opt/rh folder, run command ls -la to see if you have any devtoolset-* folder there.  Let's say you have devtoolset-8, proceed step 2.
3. Go to /etc/scl/prefixes folder, if you don't see devtoolset-8 file, you can create a new one as devtoolset-8, and type 1 line: /opt/rh, then save and quit that file.
4. Once you are done, you can call: scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash w/o any error.
   Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I am using CentOS 7.9 and I encountered the same problem after following instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1640048/how-to-properly-upgrade-gcc-on-centos-7) to install and run gcc 11. I tried launching different versions of gcc and found only `devtoolset-9` works, which corresponds to the file `devtoolset-9` in `/etc/scl/conf/` folder. So I copied `devtoolset-9` to `devtoolset-11` in the same folder, and gcc 11 gets working.

Answer (score 0):

just only runing 'yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++' is not working for me too.
i tried to run 'yum install devtoolset-8 -y, and it is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.